# Using two expressions in one bash "IF" statement

Tags: bash

I have a script that I am making, it is a very simple login script.

I was wondering if you could have two expressions in one bash "IF" statement, like so:

```
if [ $User == "root" and $Pass == "passwd" ]
```

If anyone could answer, that would be great :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `bash`, you should use the conditional expression

```
if [[ $User == root && $Pass == passed ]];
```

---

If you need to or want to use `test`, then join two test commands with `&&`:

```
if [ "$User" = root ] && [ "$Pass" = passed ];
```

Be sure to quote any parameter expansions that are used as arguments to `[`, and use `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-a` for and. And, `=` instead of `==`. Also you'd better double quote variables, otherwise you'll see a syntax error when the variables are not set.

`if [ "$User" = "root" -a "$Pass" = "passwd" ]`

Comment: `-a` was declared obsolete and should not be used. Instead, join two commands with `&&`: `[ "$User" = root ] && [ "$Pass" = passed ]`;